# Buy now functionality

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7

I found such a code to program my button to get new license from windows phone marketplace. I am not sure if it works, because when I click it in emulator, nothing happens. Can someone tell me if that code is good?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim task As New MarketplaceDetailTask()
    task.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications
    task.ContentIdentifier = "dbd49f16-69e7-408b-bda9-03afda9fa30b"
    task.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get a new license with that code, it only opens the marketplace and displays the app with id `dbd49f16-69e7-408b-bda9-03afda9fa30b`. Of course, from that page the user is able to purchase the app, so you need to update the "IsTrial/IsPurchased" state when the app is activated again. The id for your app is available when you've published your application, and go to the details page after you've clicked on your app in the dashboard at http://dev.windowsphone.com.

Also note that the appid you get from the dev center is **not equal** to the one in your WPManifest file, so don't use that one.

To get a new license, using the Trial mode that is available, use the [LicenseInformation.IsTrial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.marketplace.licenseinformation.istrial%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) method, and check it each time your application is activated. There are several tutorials available on how to create trial mode applications for windows phone, one at http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-a-Windows-Phone-7-Trial-Application-Implementation-and-Best-Practices for instance.

Comment: I did it in a similar way. Page, where I have that button can be opened only when App.IsTrial=True. I misleaded you a little bit. I meant Opening a marketplace displaying app with id i set :) sorry for that. When I click my button I get error, but I think it's normal when I'm using emulator, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you get an error in the emulator, but only if the id is not available in the store. When the app is published you will actually be able to see it in the emulator as well. But until then, you get the error you are seeing now.

Comment: So, while adding ads and setting appid,adunitid, I have to use settings from pubcenter?

Comment: I haven't actually used ads in my apps, but yes, you should use the id's from the dev center. For ads I suppose the pubCenter Application ID may be of interest, but this should be detailed in the documentation for the ad library.